# Finding formula for generating function coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, generating-functions

> You have $n$ stones. You break the stones into some number of groups,
>   and place the stones within each group into a line. You then arrange these lines in a circle. Let $s_n$ be the number of ways to do this. Find a formula for $s_n$.

So I think there are $n(n-1)$ ways to seperate into groups and $n!$ ways to form into lines? Does this give $\sum_{k=0}^{\inf}n(n-1)n!\frac{x^n}{n!}$ ? I'm not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get an answer via generating function trickery, with a combinatorial proof aided by hindsight.

Each line of $k$ stones can be arranged in $k!$ ways, so the exponential generating function for a single line is $\sum_{k\ge 1}k!\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Suppose there were $m$ lines total, with $m\ge 1$. The EGF for putting these lines in a linear order would be $\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^m$, but since we only want a circular order, we divide by $n$, for $\frac{1}m\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^m$. Summing over all $m$, we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{m\ge 1}\frac1m\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^m
&=-\log \left(1-\frac{x}{1-x}\right)
\\&=-\log(1-2x)+\log(1-x)
\\&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2^n-1}{n}x^n
\\&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\color{green}{(2^n-1)(n-1)!}\;\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align}
To explain this, note that the circular arrangement of lines can be constructed by first arranging the $n$ stones in a circle in $(n-1)!$ ways, then placing barriers between some of the stones to break them into lines. There must be at least one barrier, so this can be done in $2^n-1$ ways.